# Youtube-dl 'outtmpl' dynamic output

Tags: dynamic, output, youtube-dl

I'm trying to create a python program that allows you to dynamically choose the folder to save the download.

'outtmpl' lets you choose an output as a simple path such that

'e:/python/downloadedsongs/%(title)s.%(ext)s'

is a valid path and will let you save to the downloadedsongs folder
But With the function that defines the choose folder button

def openLocation():
global Folder_Name
Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
print(Folder_Name)

why does
f'{Folder_name}/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
not return a valid path, the program outright ignores the variable. I thought at first i was having a fstring issue because %s was pythons old format for f'strings but I have also tried these variances with no success

'outtmpl': Folder_Name + '/' + '%(title)s.%(ext)s', (no errors but cannot find output)

'outtmpl': '%(Folder_Name)s%(title)s.%(ext)s',

Answer (score 0):

`%()s` is the old version of fstrings I was conflating the two.

answer ended up looking like `'outtmpl': Folder + '/%(title)s.%(ext)s'`